# Very simple torch.tensor().to("cuda") gives CUDA error: device-side assert triggered

Tags: pytorch

All I do is,

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
torch.tensor([123,123]).to(device)
```

And I get:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

I really cannot see why.

**Edit:** Weirdly enough, I see that this happens only I after I run some code before hand. Restarting the kernel solves it. But why, some code can cause a problem like this? I cannot share the code because it's not mine but I still welcome any guesses. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CUDA runtime error (59) : device-side assert triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691563/cuda-runtime-error-59-device-side-assert-triggered)

Comment: perhaps it can be of help to someone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78037880/

Answer (score -1):

device is a string, not a tensor.
change your code to

```
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
```

now your code will work fine.
[image]

Comment: `torch.device` doesn't return a tensor so the code in the question is valid.