# CUDA error: device-side assert triggered on tensor.to(device='cuda')

Tags: pytorch, tritonserver

An ML Model is running under Triton Inference Server on a GPU instance group and after a certain amount of successful inferences starts throwing the exception:
`CUDA error: device-side assert triggered`

With `export CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1` the stacktrace points to `{key: val.to(device=COMPUTE_DEVICE) for key, val in inputs.items()}`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/triton_models/feature_based_pwsh_classifier/1/script_embeddings.py", line 129, in compute_code_embeddings
    inputs = {key: val.to(device=COMPUTE_DEVICE) for key, val in inputs.items()}
  File "/opt/triton_models/feature_based_pwsh_classifier/1/script_embeddings.py", line 129, in <dictcomp>
    inputs = {key: val.to(device=COMPUTE_DEVICE) for key, val in inputs.items()}
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

Here is a simplified form of the problematic code:

```py
max_length = llm.config.max_position_embeddings

# inputs is a dict with keys: [input_ids, attention_mask]
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt', max_length=max_length, truncation=True, padding=True)

# Move the inputs to the CUDA device
inputs = {key: val.to(device=COMPUTE_DEVICE) for key, val in inputs.items()}

with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = llm(**inputs)
```

Where:

- `COMPUTE_DEVICE` is `torch.device('cuda')`
- `llm` and `tokenizer` are loaded via `transformers` library from [Graph-CodeBERT](https://huggingface.co/microsoft/graphcodebert-base/)
- once the exception occurs, all following InderenceRequests yield error, and the Triton Server needs to be restarted
- the `inputs` looks valid with: `dtype:torch.int64, size:(1, xxx), device:cpu, has_NAN:False, has_inf:False`
- GPU VRAM is usually under 20% when the exception occurs

Help and recommendation are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by using [max_position_embeddings](https://huggingface.co/microsoft/graphcodebert-base/blob/main/config.json) of size `514` from `graphcodebert` config:

```
max_length = llm.config.max_position_embeddings
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt', max_length=max_length, truncation=True, padding=True)
```

while in fact, the `512`, which is standard for [BERT](https://huggingface.co/google-bert/bert-base-uncased/blob/main/config.json) models allowed Tokenizer to produce valid outputs.

Few notes on debugging process:

- Set environment value `export CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1`
- Increase logging by adding `--log-verbose` to the Triton IS command: `tritonserver --model-repository /opt/triton_models/ --log-verbose=1`
- Look for the **first** exception, which in my case was:

  ```
  ../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1292: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [523,0,0], thread: [31,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/triton_models/feature_based_pwsh_classifier/1/script_embeddings.py", line 140, in compute_code_embeddings
      outputs = llm(**inputs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
      return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
      return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py", line 828, in forward
      embedding_output = self.embeddings(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
      return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
      return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py", line 130, in forward
      position_embeddings = self.position_embeddings(position_ids)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
      return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
  Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
  ```
- It turns out that once `CUDA error` is thrown, the model enters undetermined state and **any** following CUDA Tensor operation will produce `CUDA error: device-side assert triggered`, heavily polluting the logs
- Manually collect offending `text` and replicate failing operations in local Jupyter Notebook on a CPU, which caused:

  ```
  IndexError: index out of range in self
  ```

Helpful discussion:

- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-assertion-srcindex-srcselectdimsize-failed-on-gpu-for-torch-cat/1804/9